# Error in repository initialization

Tags: linux, opensuse, yast, zypper

I am running opensuse 12.1. When I start up YaST software manager I get an error:

```
There was an error in the repository initialization.
Error refreshing service Synergy (http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/repository):

Parse error: repoindex.xml[114] Entity 'copy' not defined
```

I would like to just delete this repository entry but can't figure out how. The output of zypper lr is:

```
# | Alias                  | Name                       | Enabled | Refresh
--+------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------
1 | openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4 | openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4     | Yes     | Yes    
2 | repo-debug             | openSUSE-12.1-Debug        | No      | Yes    
3 | repo-debug-update      | openSUSE-12.1-Update-Debug | No      | Yes    
4 | repo-non-oss           | openSUSE-12.1-Non-Oss      | Yes     | Yes    
5 | repo-source            | openSUSE-12.1-Source       | No      | Yes    
6 | repo-update            | openSUSE-12.1-Update       | Yes     | Yes
```